# Can add custom control to ToolBox, but cannot create dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, dll, custom-controls

I've created my own custom control and added it to my toolbox.  It works, I can drag it to the Form, access its properties though code ect... But I cannot create it dynamically?  Like for instance a button would be:

```
Button btn = new Button();
```

But when I try my control:

```
CustomControl x = new CustomControl();
```

I get: "Type or namespace name 'CustomControl' could not be found"

I add the .dll to my references and I try the above code, to only get: "'CustomControl' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'"

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Same error: `new System.IO()`

Comment: Can you post the definition for your CustomControl?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo in there?  You said * CustomeControl*?  Can you please clarify?

Comment: Yeah that was a typo, but it still doesn't work when I fix it.

Comment: I get: "Type or namespace name 'CustomeControl' could not be found"

Maybe a typo?? CustomeControl should be CustomControl

Comment: I got it working.  Didn't have the using statement of the .dll that was added to the reference >.< Sorry for the trouble, its my first custom control.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like maybe your CustomControl is in a namespace called CustomControl.  If that's the case, then rename one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `namespace` instead `type`. `namespace` is just a Case and you can not create a new one using the last namespace. try to find what class is in the namespace and construct a new one(using `CustomControl.Cl c=new CustomControl.Cl();` but not try to use  `CustomControl x = new CustomControl();`

---

I think the reason is that the `namespace` does not have any `constructor` ant it can't construct but `class` have `constructor`.
because the namespace's concept if for Classification your classes and another things and it doesn't exist int the general code.